# Jailbroken iOS 10.3.3; iCleaner won't open; can't reinstall/turn on tweaks

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, cydia

A couple of days ago, I disabled all tweaks (with iCleaner), and then upgraded it to v7.7.2. I have tried downgrading it and installing it from different sources, but I can't open it to enable all tweaks. Now with my phone fully jailbroken (instead of semi), I am still unable to open iCleaner. Is there any way to manually revert whatever iCleaner did (or delete all of iCleaners data so I can launch it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully fixed, iCleaner also works, but for some reason when I downgraded rocketbootstrap to v6 everything re-installed and worked properly (except for KarenLocalizer stuff, but that was fixed by borrowing libkarenlocalizer.dylib off of a different device)